# Como resolver este erro ao utilizar a Room Persistence Library com Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, library

Quando mando executo o app, recebo um crash assim na primeira chamada ao banco de dados:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.../....ActivityLogin}: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for ....database.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

Minhas dependências relacionadas ao banco de dados:

```
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

P.S.: Não estou usando o kapt na minha aplicação.

Comment: *"Não estou usando o kapt na minha aplicação."*  -  mas deveria estar se quer usar a Room em kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

[@ramaral](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2541/ramaral) resolveu o mistério!

> If you previously used the Android support for annotation processors,
>   replace usages of the annotationProcessor configuration with kapt. If
>   your project contains Java classes, kapt will also take care of them.

[fonte](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html)